# Backbone-Marionette Composite view template itemViewContainer scope issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I have a complex view nesting(similar to fb feed) like below:

CompositeView(loop for feeds)-> LayoutView(for different body type and comment regions) -> one layout view(almost 20 different types switches on condition) and a Composite View (both uses 2 regions of parent layout)-> ItemView(inside composite view)

Here, the inner composite view has a ul with class "ullisting" (itemViewContainer), but here the data list is getting shared btn composite view instances; So what happens here is comments of one feed get displayed in another.

I resolved this by changing "ullisting" from class to unique ids. But I feel this as a bug(or a mistake from my part) because the data should not be shared even if itemViewContainer uses a class as identifier.

[image]

Comment: Strange behavior. `itemViewContainer` in CompositeView scopes to that view's `el`. Did you have more than one ".ullisting" in your CompositeView?

Comment: Please post the relevant 2nd compositeview code and more important the view that renders this 2nd compositeview

Comment: how are you passing the data down through the VIew hierarchy?  If its as a collection, at some point you'll need to filter out the irrelevant data and only pass the stuff you need.

Comment: Please see below js files; feed.js contains outer composite view and its child layout view; comments.js contains child composite view of layout view.
http://dev12.ispg.in/temp_downloads/test/feed.js
http://dev12.ispg.in/temp_downloads/test/comments.js
No, .ullisting is not repeating in template